# changing multiple WHERE clauses at once

Tags: sql

I have a simple query that I run over multiple files, and use a UNION to combine to results.  one of my WHERE clauses a date that needs to be changed.  instead of changing this at every position in my select statement, I was wondering if there was a way to change the date parameter on each file at once?  in the example below I would like to change the CYYMMDD in both places without having to manual update in both positions.

```
SELECT

POATYP,
POACO#,
PHVND,
POAOR#,
POACOD,
POAAMT + POARC$ AS COLUMN0000

FROM 

CORP01.DSFILES95.DSPOACA DSPOACA,  
CORP01.DSFILES95.DSPOHDR DSPOHDR 

WHERE

DSPOACA.POACO# = DSPOHDR.PHCO#
AND DSPOACA.POAOR# = DSPOHDR.PHPO#
AND ( POATYP = A
AND PHPOD >= CYYMMDD) 

UNION SELECT 

POATYP,
POACO#,
PHVND,
POAOR#,
POACOD,
POAAMT + POARC$ AS COLUMN0000

FROM 

CORP01.DSFILES17.DSPOACA DSPOACA,  
CORP01.DSFILES17.DSPOHDR DSPOHDR 

WHERE 

DSPOACA.POACO# = DSPOHDR.PHCO#
AND DSPOACA.POAOR# = DSPOHDR.PHPO#
AND ( POATYP = A
AND PHPOD >= CYYMMDD)
```

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Why not make this a stored procedure and pass in the date as a parameter?

Comment: Does your query editor allow you to use ctrl-H?

Comment: Do the UNION ALL without where clauses in a derived table. Put the WHERE clause outside it.

Comment: I am using Showcase Query to generate reports on files in AS400 I-series @GordonLinoff

Comment: I do not know how to do what your are stating @JamesH  if you could clarify I could give it a whirl

Comment: I tried using CTRL-H @TabAlleman, but nothing happened.  it may not be supported

Comment: @jarlh, could you clarify for me what your are saying?  I do not understand, sorry

Comment: @JCS, a derived table solution is pretty similar to Gordon Linoff's query. Take a look at that answer.

Answer (score 4):

I sometimes use CTEs for this purpose

```
with params as (
      select CYYMMDD as cyymmdd
     )
select *
from ((select . . .
       from params cross join
            . . .
       where . . . PHPOD >= CYYMMDD
      ) union
      (select . . .
       from params cross join
            . . .
       where . . .
      ) . . .
     ) x;
```

Notes:

- You should use `UNION ALL` unless you intend to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.
- You should learn to use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- In some databases, you can also do something similar with variables, but CTEs are supported by most databases.